# How to establish secure communication over MQTT using PSK in Java?

Tags: java, mqtt, tls-psk

I want to establish secure communication over mqtt using PSK. I explored a lot but everywhere they are using certificates.

Comment: I'm not aware of any Java MQTT library that supports TLS-PSK at this time.

Comment: Is it. Can't we use SSLContext for PSK or bouncy castle library?

Comment: I meant out of the box, but looking at Paho, you should be able to attach a SocketFactory from a SSLContext with a custom KeyManager. I'll try and have a play later

Comment: ok let me know how u r doing it as i m new to all this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A solution could be to put [stunnel](https://www.stunnel.org) in front of your MQTT client.

stunnel would act as a reverse proxy for connections.

The config options would be `PSKidentity` and `PSKsecrets`.